# Page updates after Refresh

Tags: php, magento, caching

Currently i have a site in magento.When i update anything the page loads but doesn't show the updated value. For example quantity of items on cart odesnot show updated when i update but shows when i refresh the page. When i refresh the page again it shows the updated value. This issue is not only on cart page rather on all front end and back end pages. I have tried disabling all extensions. The interesting fact is that the site is working fine on my local system. Any guess what might cause this issue.

Comment: check your console, most probably there is a javascript error there (updating of cart etc. is done using js)

Comment: I have checked but there is no error in console neither in logs. This issue is on all pages . If you need i can give url of site and you can check. Actually it does update sometime while doesn't update the other time. I have checked that when it doesnot update the control doesnot go to that phtml code. Wonder if its any server issue as it is working fine on my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transferred the files to other server and it was working fine. So it was confirm that it was something to do with server issue. I matched phpinfo on both servers and enabling disabling modules at last reached to a comclusion. Varnish Cache was installed on live server that was causing the issue.
Thanks @Giorgio for struggling with me to find the answer to my problem.